# layer vs quickblox baas comparison

Tags: parse-platform, layer, quickblox

layer vs quickblox , which is better(easier to implement,performance features)

for messages,voip, and video chat,
and do I need to add parse.com with those messaging solutions for content storage.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the differentiating points are:

1. Quickblox supports video and audio calling, layer doesn't.
2. Layer provides SDK for iOS, android and Javascript & unity sdk are in queue. Quickblox provides sdk for iOS, android and js.
3. All the above mentioned are only for client. If you want to control something from your server then you have to use Rest APIs.
4. Layer provides Rest and Websocket API but Quickblox only provides rest API.
5. Quickblox [states](https://quickblox.com/blog/quickblox-for-nodejs) that their js sdk can be used on node.js server. But I was getting `This browser not supported` error in connecting to chat from node.js server. The same error is also specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430937/connect-quickblox-chat-server-from-node-js#comment55839009_29430937). This means that there is not way to get real time notification on new message/user on your server with Quickblox.
6. Quickblox free tier customer support sucks (for eg. see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysDaM.jpg) (no response on any ticket), [here](https://quickblox.com/blog/quickblox-for-nodejs/#comment-2388598334) and [here](https://twitter.com/knoxxs/status/672327623402496000)). I found Layer's support very good.
7. Layer's documentation is too good. Quickblox's is confusing. Also quickblox have no doc describing there basic concepts.
8. Layer also provides support for [UIKs](https://atlas.layer.com/ios).
9. Quickblox provides in house user management, layer does not. But you can use Parse to do that as defined in [layer docs](https://developer.layer.com/docs/android/guides#parse).
10. Layer has platform API to bulk and system level actions like sending announcements and they also provide engagement analytics on those.
11. I also find [this small layer's feature](https://developer.layer.com/docs/platform#specifying-a-sender) very useful.

There are many more differences. I just started using chat Baas last week. Will update the answer with time.